# Word transform to click in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a span; I want to change the word of the text in span when I click this word to English likewise translator.

Example:
var from = ['Hallo','Welt'];
var to = ['Hello','World];

This paragraph is a value of span.... Hello World

Comment: What exactly is the problem and what exactly is your question? This is just you telling us what your task is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span id='demo'>Hallo Welt Ich bin ein Programmer</span>

var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
var de = [];
de['Hallo'] = 'Hello'; 
de['Welt'] = 'World'; 

function translate(e) {
  var key = e.target.innerHTML;
  e.target.innerHTML = de[key];
}

function prepare() {
  var words = demo.innerHTML.split(" ");
  var content = '';
  words.forEach(function(element) {
      if (typeof de[element] !== 'undefined') {
        content += '<span class="de">' + element + '</span> ';
      } else {
        content += element + ' ';
      }

  });

  demo.innerHTML = content;

  var list = demo.getElementsByClassName("de");
  list = Array.prototype.slice.call(list);
  list.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.onclick = translate;
  });

}

prepare();
```

Comment: yes, I know... But I need with Array. 
<span id = 'demo'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</span>

var from = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', ... ]; var to = ['Hello', 'I',... , '' ];

Comment: You can scan the InnerHTML of 'demo', define which words are in the 'from' Array and set for them ids and Listeners to another 'to' Array.

Comment: joooo, do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your trying to do something like this:

```
object.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jooola/L08a95m4/. 

no work??? Each word to click?